# Select a Facebook Page for each Recipe in IFTTT?

Tags: facebook-pages, if-this-then-that

I would like to select different Facebook pages for different recipes in my [IFTTT](http://ifttt.com). I don't see any option to select it once the channel is created.

Is there anyway I can do this or I have to create a different IFTTT account for each one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately you can only have one account activated for each IFTTT channel - so you will need different accounts.

However they supposedly have it in the [works](http://qr.ae/ROpbhi).

Alternatively, you could you a competitor of theirs, I know [Zapier](https://zapier.com/) allows this.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! Zapier looks up, as IFTTT looks down... Switching!